# Azure WebJob, how to be notified if it stops?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an azure webjob that runs continuously.  I'd like to be notified if it stops or is aborted.  Is there an event that gets called on stop or abort that I can trigger an email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the WebJob SDK, then you can do that using the new `ErrorTrigger` and `SendGrid` extensions. Check this [wiki on how to set that up](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Error-Monitoring). But here is a sample code (copied from the wiki above) that uses both extensions to send an email if an error occurred 10 times in 30 minutes window with a throttle up to 1 hour

```cs
public static void ErrorMonitor(
    [ErrorTrigger("0:30:00", 10, Throttle = "1:00:00") TraceFilter filter,
    [SendGrid] SendGridMessage message)
{
    message.Subject = "WebJobs Error Alert";
    message.Text = filter.GetDetailedMessage(5)
}
```

If you aren't using the WebJob SDK, then unfortunately there aren't any events for continuous webjobs. There is [only one for triggered jobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/3f22884d322d5a56fa85569fec8bd1b4f4c132ae/Kudu.Core/Jobs/TriggeredJobsManager.cs#L250-L260).