# How to get notification when webjob status was aborted in azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Azure WebJob, how to be notified if it aborted?

(1)Always Availability is on for the service.
(2) SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2000.
            WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2000.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure WebJob, how to be notified if it stops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159594/azure-webjob-how-to-be-notified-if-it-stops)

Comment: Is your question related to the one mentioned on the previous comment ? If not, could add more information on what you are trying to do

Comment: My question is related to the same. But as i'm new to this. can you please help me on this one where can i put the logic.

Answer (score 0):

> But as i'm new to this. can you please help me on this one where can i put the logic

You could add the logic in the Function.cs file.  For more information you could refer to the detail steps

**Steps:**

1.follow official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#create-a-project) to create a webjob project.

2.Add Functions.cs in the project

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions;
using SendGrid;

public class Functions
    {
        //demo webjob trigger
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(message);
        }
        // error monitor
        public static void ErrorMonitor([ErrorTrigger("0:30:00", 10, Throttle = "1:00:00")]TraceFilter filter, [SendGrid] SendGridMessage message)
        {
            message.Subject = "WebJobs Error Alert";
            message.Text = filter.GetDetailedMessage(5);
        }
    }
```

3.If want to use ErrorTrigger and SendGrid we need to config it in the Program.cs file.

```
static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            }
            config.UseCore();
            config.UseSendGrid(new SendGridConfiguration
            {
                ApiKey = "xxxxx",
                FromAddress = new Email("emailaddress","name"),
                ToAddress =  new Email("emailaddress","name")
            });
            var host = new JobHost(config);
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
```

4.If we want to test it locally, we need to add  Storage connection string in the App Settings collection.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="{storage connection string}" />
</connectionStrings>
```